# Highlight one city at a time and remove color fill when other City is hovered on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the color fill on the old city when another city is hovered on. Currently when i hover over the map it highlights every city when hovered over.

```
$('area').hover(function () {

        var coordinates = $(this).attr("coords");

        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        v

    });
```

Comment: please share your html code also

Comment: its too big. its a  jquery question

Comment: I think clearing the canvas right after getting the context should fix it. Also, there's no need to get the canvas element and the context every time you hover the area, do it once and keep them in memory

Comment: @JonasGrumann i am just starting jquery i clearly dont know how to do that

Comment: What does the code for the map look like? Is it an image file or drawn on a canvas? We need some more information in order to help you.

Comment: its is a map of USA states

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since you commented on my comment I'm gonna leave you the code which I think might fix you issue:

```
$('area').hover(function () {

        var coordinates = $(this).attr("coords");
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );
        var points = coordinatess.split(",");
        context.moveTo(points[0], points[1]);
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2) {
         var   x = parseInt(points[i]);
           var y = parseInt(points[i + 1]);
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            context.fillStyle = 'blue';
            context.fill();
        }
    });
```

Comment: In this case I'm afraid we don't have enough information. You need to provide us with more code or give us a link to a jsfiddle or a page where we can see you problem